# How does kotlintest test spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlintest

The integration test of Spring boot application always starts the web server firstly.

The simplest test of spring boot test looks like below, how does migrate it using kotlintest instead?

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ReportApplicationTests {

    @Test
    fun `Server can be launched`() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I've got it set up: firstly, make sure to reference JUnit 5 instead of 4, e.g. I've got this in the `dependencies` section of my `build.gradle`:

```
testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}"
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test"
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit"
testImplementation "io.kotlintest:kotlintest-extensions-spring:3.1.10"
testImplementation 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.1.10'
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1"
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1"
```

Also add this to `build.gradle`:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Then in your integration test class have this (notice the override of `listeners`, without which it won't work):

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import io.kotlintest.spring.SpringListener

@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = [MyApplication::class])
class MyTestStringSpec : StringSpec() {
    override fun listeners() = listOf(SpringListener)

    init {
        // Tests go in here
    }
}
```

Obviously you can replace `StringSpec` with any of the other Kotlin Test [testing styles](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/doc/styles.md), e.g. `FunSpec`, `ShouldSpec`, etc.

Comment: It does not work for me. Could you pls share a sample project to demonstrate it?

Comment: Apologies, I missed a step: you need to override `listeners` and return `SpringListener`. Have updated my answer. If you're still stuck let me know and I'll stick an example repo up on github.

Comment: @YoniGibbs I don't believe you need that many dependencies. I set it up using only `testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}"`, `testImplementation 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.1.10'` and `testImplementation "io.kotlintest:kotlintest-extensions-spring:3.1.10"`

Comment: That's great to know. Thanks @Kerooker.

Answer (score 7):

Update: From version 4.3+, somethings have changes.

### Version 4.3+ (newer)

KotlinTest was renamed to Kotest. The `SpringExtension` is the class to integrate with spring. [The documentation](https://kotest.io/docs/extensions/spring.html) on how to use it is pretty simple.

In addition to `Kotest` dependency, you should also add `SpringExtension`:

```
testImplementation("io.kotest.extensions:kotest-extensions-spring:1.0.0")
```

and then include `SpringExtension` to your extensions. From then on you can use everything `Spring Boot` has to offer in tests, such as `ContextConfiguration` and others:

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyTestSpec : FunSpec() {
   override fun extensions() = listOf(SpringExtension)

   init {
     test("I'm inside a Spring context!") { }
   }
}
```

### Version 3.3.2 (very old)

Kotlintest has a [very nice guide](http://kotest.io/docs/framework/extensions/spring.html) on how to setup Spring Extension to test Spring Framework.

Basically, in addition to `KotlinTest` dependency, you also add it's `Spring Extension`:

```
testImplementation ("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.3.2") // KT dependency
testImplementation("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-extensions-spring:3.3.2") // KT Spring Extensions
```

And then you include the `SpringListener` **and** `SpringBootTest` to your code:

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import io.kotlintest.spring.SpringListener

@SpringBootTest
class SpringExample : FreeSpec() {

    override fun listeners() = listOf(SpringListener)

    init {
        "Verify context loads" {

        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to add `SpringListener` to every test you create, you can configure it globally using `ProjectConfig`. ProjectConfig is explained in [KotlinTest Documentation](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/doc/reference.md#project-config)

Comment: Recently listener was renamed: 
"In Kotest 4.3 and earlier, the Spring extension was called SpringListener. This extension has now been deprecated in favour of SpringExtension. The usage is the same, but the SpringExtension has more functionality. " See https://kotest.io/docs/extensions/spring.html#testcontexts

Comment: Perfect, @OliverEisenbarth. I'll update the answer